# "Expected Declaration" with "{"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Such a beginner question but I am getting this error and I have tried to rearrange the braces in a million different ways but still return this error one way or another. I have managed to arrange the braces in a fashion to return only one error in one place. Here is a picture of the location of the error as well as the code.

[image]

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TwoCVs
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}

class FirstCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        guard buttonOne != nil else { return }
        buttonOne.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Marker Felt", size: 20)
        buttonOne.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        buttonOne.clipsToBounds = true
        buttonOne.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        buttonOne.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        }
    }

class SecondCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonTwo: UIButton!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        guard buttonTwo != nil else { return }
        buttonTwo.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Marker Felt", size: 20)
        buttonTwo.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        buttonTwo.clipsToBounds = true
        buttonTwo.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        buttonTwo.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }
}

class ThirdCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonThree: UIButton!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        guard buttonThree != nil else { return }
        buttonThree.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Marker Felt", size: 20)
        buttonThree.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        buttonThree.clipsToBounds = true
        buttonThree.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        buttonThree.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        
        }
}

class TwoCollectionsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstCV: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondCV: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdCV: UICollectionView!
    @IBAction func Buttons(_ sender: Any) {
        if let btn = sender as? UIButton {
            print(btn.restorationIdentifier!)
                guard let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }
                guard let id = Int(button.restorationIdentifier!) else {return}
            if id == 0 {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "Good Work", sender: btn)
            }
            else if id == 1 {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "Nice Try", sender: btn)
            }
            else if id == 6 {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "Second 1", sender: btn)
               
        }
        }
    
    }
    
    let firstData: [String] = [
        "Good Work", "Nice Try", "Btn 3", "Btn 4", "Btn 5", "Btn 6"
    ]

    let secondData: [String] = [
        "Second 1", "Second 2", "Second 3", "Second 4", "Second 5", "Second 6", "Second 7"
    ]
    let thirdData:  [String] = [
    "Action 1", "Action 2", "Action 3", "Action 4", "Action 5", "Action 6"]

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        firstCV.dataSource = self
        firstCV.delegate = self
        
        secondCV.dataSource = self
        secondCV.delegate = self
        
        thirdCV.dataSource = self
        thirdCV.delegate = self
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // if it's the First Collection View
        if collectionView == firstCV {
            return firstData.count
            
        // it's not the First Collection View, so it's the Second one
        return secondData.count
    
        }
    
        return thirdData.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        if collectionView == firstCV {
              let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath) as! FirstCollectionViewCell
              cell.buttonOne.setTitle(firstData[indexPath.item], for: []) //allows for button title change in code above
             cell.buttonOne.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row)"
              return cell
          }
          // it's not the First Collection View, so it's the Second one
          let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondCollectionViewCell
          cell.buttonTwo.setTitle(secondData[indexPath.item], for: [])
          cell.buttonTwo.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row + firstData.count)"
          return cell
    }
{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "thirdCell", for: indexPath) as! ThirdCollectionViewCell
        cell.buttonThree.setTitle(thirdData[indexPath.item], for: [])
        cell.buttonThree.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row + secondData.count)"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but `guard buttonOne` is pointless. If the button is connected in Interface Builder (which cannot change at runtime) it can never be `nil` in `viewDidLoad` or later

Comment: Why do you need so many brackets, what is it you are trying to achieve with them?

Comment: Im fairly new so Im just trying to have a function code! If you have code update recommendations ill take them!

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe you want your last method to be like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    if collectionView == firstCV {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath) as! FirstCollectionViewCell
        cell.buttonOne.setTitle(firstData[indexPath.item], for: []) //allows for button title change in code above
        cell.buttonOne.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    } else if collectionView == secondCV {
            // it's not the First Collection View, so it's the Second one
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondCollectionViewCell
        cell.buttonTwo.setTitle(secondData[indexPath.item], for: [])
        cell.buttonTwo.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row + firstData.count)"
        return cell
    } else if collectionView == thirdCV {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "thirdCell", for: indexPath) as! ThirdCollectionViewCell
        cell.buttonThree.setTitle(thirdData[indexPath.item], for: [])
        cell.buttonThree.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row + secondData.count)"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: And I do recommend you to optimize your code cause there are too many duplicate codes with the same function, if you have extra energy.

Comment: Once I figure out how to do so, that will be a good idea. If you can reply with any code updates I will gladly take them! Im fairly new.